# Set width of tabular column to the width of tabular numerals

Tags: tables, fontspec, width, lengths

Take the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oldstyle, tabular]{libertine}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\period}
\settowidth{\period}{9999--9999}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{\period}l}
        2002--2005 & Put some text and numbers 0123456789 here
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example, I've defined the width of the left column (which is set to be ragged left) to be the width of eight tabular (i.e. monospaced) numerals and a hyphen.

But what I actually want is to set the width of the left column as above, but use proportional numerals outside of the first column. The example below obviously doesn't work, since this will set all numerals in the document to be proportional:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oldstyle, proportional]{libertine} % <- change is here only
\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\period}
\settowidth{\period}{9999--9999}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{\period}l}
        2002--2005 & Put some text and numbers 0123456789 here
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So my question is: How can I set the width of the first column to be based on tabular numerals, and then use tabular numerals in that column in the document, but use proportional numerals elsewhere?

If this is best done with `fontspec`, then I'm open to using that instead.

Comment: why not use an `l` column, why use a `p` column here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I want the columns to line up with other tables in the same document in which the content of the first column doesn't match the width of `2002-2005`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `\tabfig` command that chooses oldstyle digits in tabular format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  oldstyle,
  proportional
]{libertine} 
\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\period}

\newcommand{\tabfig}{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TOsF}\selectfont}

\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\period}{\tabfig 0000--0000}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft\tabfig}p{\period}l}
2002--2005 & Put some text and numbers 0123456789 here
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the delaying of the measurement after LaTeX has issued `\normalfont`.

[image]

Comment: Great! Based on this, I assume I can use the same trick with `fontspec`, i.e. `\newcommand{\tabfig}{\newfontfamily{...}}` and then use `\raggedleft\tabfig`?

Comment: @Sverre Not certainly with `\newfontfamily`: `\newcommand{\tabfig}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}}`

Comment: I just tested, and it works fine with `\newfontfamily\tabfig[Ligatures = {TeX}, Numbers = {OldStyle, Monospaced}]{Linux Libertine O}` for me. I've learned from Khaled Hosny, I believe, that it's better to use `\newfontfamily` than to use `\addfontfeatures`. (I don't know what I was thinking in my previous comment suggesting `\newcommand` etc.).